# Real-time web service java using axis2

Tags: java, web-services, real-time, tomcat7, apache-axis

Purpose: 
I'm trying to make a real-time web service in Java. When there're changes in database, the data in clients(probably Android client) will be changed automatically without refreshing.

Platform:
I'm using Tomcat 7 container and Axis2.

Problems:
I'm stuck in the way to approach. I've realized that there were 2 ways:
1. When the data in server changes, notice to all the clients. Web-service allows us to do this, but I don't know what clients I have to inform!
2. Clients connect to the server, keep the connection alive and whenever there's a change, update data. However, if the client is the handheld, it will consume much power and data exchange over 3G network.

I know that's a complicated problem. So I just want to ask if there is an efficient way to approach? And if possible, anyone can give me one example of realtime web service like this?
I've searched over many pages, but nothing's helpful. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Tkx!

Comment: you might want to look into android push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a requirement to use webservices or Axis? Otherwise, you might be interested in [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websocket). These are connections over plain HTTP that provide two way communication. Your clients will connect to your server, and as soon as new data is available your server can push data to every connection it knows of, thus informing all clients that are connected.

Comment: Yes, it's the requirement to use Web service but Axis is just an option.

Comment: I've found it's possible to integrate Websocket with axis2. Thank you!